# Locally visible typedef for function parameter and function body

Tags: c++

I want to know if there is any way to `typedef` locally for use with function parameters and function body.

Like in the following case:

```
// typedef: solution 1, visible everywhere in the namespace

void func(/*really long type*/ param1, /*many more params of same/different type*/) {

    // typedef: solution 2, cannot use for params

    /*more variables using the same typedef inside the body */

}
```

I know I can have the `typedef` inside the function body, but that would not be usable for the parameters. I wanted to have it more readable, especially considering the long type name and multiple parameters of the same type.
`typedef` outside the function would pollute the namespace, which I want to prevent unless there is no other choice.

Is there a way that I am not aware of that achieves the above while being more localized? if not, which solution is recommended.

Comment: place `func` inside inner namespace and then `using inner::func`?

Comment: I find your requirement a bit surprising (or I misunderstood your intention). Assume you had a type which is visible only in function parameters and body... What type do you intend to use for the arguments when you want to call this function from elsewhere?

Comment: I will have the type completely spelled out there, which is okay since that won't be done many times.

Comment: @Jarod42 That is a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
namespace inner {

  using type = really_long_type;  // typedef works as well

  void func(type t, /* ... */) {
    // ...
  }
}

using inner::func;
```